# How to open txt file and put content in tsv file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, text, io

I'm new to python, and have a very basic understanding of file io.

I want to open a text file, change the formatting of the content inside it and place that changed content into a new tsv file.

I know how to open the file with

```
old_file = open('old_file.txt')
```

but have no idea how to read it line by line without changing the original text file, or how to make a new file for the changes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: to read lines `for line in old_file: print(line)` But if you want to change lines in `'old_file.txt'` then you have to read all to memory, change it in memory and write all back to file `'old_file.txt'`. If you want to put new lines only in new file then you can read line by line, change line and write line in new file.

Comment: yeah I dont want to change the original file, only the new one. But thats the thing I don't know how to do that

Comment: `f = open(filename)`, `f.read()`, `f.readlines()`, `f.close()`, `g = open(filename, 'w')`, `g.write()`, `g.close()`

Comment: Could you elaborate on what kind of data you're reading in? You stated in your question a `tsv` file, do you mean `csv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
fp = open('new_file.txt','w') 
for line in open('old_file.txt','r').readlines():
   new_line = 'do modifications on line and store to new line'
   fp.write(new_line)
fp.close()
```